# MySQL - Full text search

Tags: mysql, full-text-search

I'm using a MySQL db with a full-text index of the two fields (name and aliases).

It is a videogames database

codice:

```
SELECT name,MATCH (name,aliases) AGAINST ('inFamous: Second Son') AS relevance
FROM games_search
ORDER BY relevance DESC;
```

With this query I get the following results

codice:

```
inFamous 2                     9.150630950927734
inFamous: Second Son           9.150630950927734
inFamous                       8.947185516357422
inFamous: Festival of Blood    8.947185516357422
```

Why the first two results have the same relevance?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Full text search in MySQL ignores two types of words:  stop words and words shorted than some threshhold.

You can read the list of stop words [here](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/fulltext-stopwords.html).  Of particular interest in your case is the word `'second'`.

By default, only words with 4 characters or longer are kept for search purposes.  Hence, `'son'` is ignored.  So, your query is equivalent to:

```
SELECT name, MATCH (name,aliases) AGAINST ('inFamous:') AS relevance
FROM games_search
ORDER BY relevance DESC;
```

I am not sure why these are higher than the last two.  I speculate that the relevancy is treating a perfect match (minus stop words and short words) as slightly higher than an imperfect match.